# JavaScript assoc array add key value pairs unexpected result

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably entirely obvious, but why am I not getting the expected JSON string when adding a key-value pair to this JavaScript array?

Next step: As code reveals, I actually wish to have two data sets in the object.

[**jsFiddle here** - Weird, at the moment it only "works" in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/s7tdq469/)

```
var myKey = "123", myVal="Car";
var arrSummat = new Array();

$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    arrSummat["987"] = "Boat";
    //arrSummat[myKey] = myVal;
    var test = JSON.stringify(arrSummat);
    alert(test);
});
```

Comment: Step one: `Array` should be used only as an array. Not an object or "associative array". If you want an associative array use an object: `arrSummat = {}; arrSummat["987"] = "Boat";`

Comment: Here's your sample as an object: http://jsfiddle.net/s7tdq469/1/

Comment: Aaaargh. Do you have any idea how many blogs/tuts/pages I visited discussing this issue and all I found was that assoc arrays in js are really Objects, and then they defined them as I did above. Sincere thanks for solution. Please add as answer for acceptance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript building an associative array* or hash map or object may not be terribly obvious. For one, everything is ultimately an object and so the syntax used with associative arrays is valid on everything that isn't an "associate array" which is probably where the confusion arises. First let's address the issue at hand. You probably wanted to use an object instead of an array:

```
arrSummat = {};
arrSummat["987"] = "Boat";
console.log(JSON.stringify(arrSummat)); // => {"987":"Boat"}
```

When running your fiddle (in Chrome) I pretty much get an array with 986 `null` values and then `"Boat"` (I may be wrong, I'm not hand counting the `null`s in that alert).

Now that you're original question is resolved I'd like to point out two things you may want to start doing differently:

Prefer shorthand syntax for objects and arrays. The two examples are functionally the same but you should prefer the second for most purposes.

```
var myArr = new Array();
var myObj = new Object();
```

Is the same as:

```
var myArr = [];
var myObj = {};
```

The shorthand can even come with some basic values:

```
var myArr = [1, 2, 3];
var myObj = {one: "1", two: "2"};
```

Secondly, never use an `Array` object as anything other than an array. It is syntactically valid to do so but it will produce unexpected results (as you have seen here).

- There is no "associative array" in JavaScript, but Objects are commonly used as a substitute and provide similar functionality.

[**Revised jsFiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/s7tdq469/1/)

Comment: Fantastic response and worth more upvotes than received. Thx too for connecting the number of `null` with the value provided -- I didn't notice that. Wish I could upvote again.

Comment: @crashwap Thanks for your kind words, I'm just glad you were able to get past your issue and move forward!